# Vertical/Horizontal centring a number in a div contained in a table-cell

Tags: html, css

I need to centre a number (vertically and horizontally) which is contained within a div (or anything else) - this div needs to be 60px in width and height, to be a circle, and it needs to be vertically and horizontally centred within a table-cell.

All I have been able to come up with so far, is centring the div within the table-cell, but no matter what I try, I simply can't vertically centre the text within that div.

Could someone help please.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7us71z9k/4/)

```
.outer {
    display: table;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 50%;
}
.number-box {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px
}
.number {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    font-size: 28px;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="number-box">
            <div class="number">1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## EDIT

This is what I was actually after:

```
<style>
.outer {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.cell1 {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 10%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.cell2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 22px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 90%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.number-box {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.number {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="cell1">
        <div class="number-box">
            <div class="number">1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell2">
        xxxxas asd ad asd asd asd asd asda adsasd asd asd asdkajsd asd asda sd adasd asdasdasdasd ad asd asd asd asd asd asd as dad asd asdadasda sda dasdasdadasdad
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Friends don't let friends do inline styles. :-)

Comment: Thanks for making that change. Inline style though is useful when you develop but yes okay, next time I will reformat.

Comment: No, it's not. Add classes and a nearby embedded style tag. You'll thank yourself later for not having to move all that junk around. You just copy and paste to a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I removed one of your elements. It could probably be replaced without much trouble.

```
.outer {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.number-box {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 70px auto 0;
}
.number {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="number-box">
        <div class="number">1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7us71z9k/10)

The one caveat here is that `font-size` and `line-height` must match.

Comment: Thanks. This is a possible solution but not the one I look for because you actually shift the number to centre it. But if you change the font-size then the centring is not right any longer. I'd ideally like to have an automatic way of centring the number (using vertical-align: middle).

Comment: Thanks - I updated the fiddle to reflect exactly what I was looking for which was to centre the div within the table-cell. Thx for your answer.

Comment: Actually, interesting enough, it works because the height is defined in outer. If you remove the height, then centring vertically doesn't work any longer. Imagine the circle is inside a table cell and that the table-cell on the right on this cell has lots of text ... then the circle on the left won't be vertically centred unless you specify the height.